# Show that x is geometric distributed

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have this relation
\begin{align}
&(1) & P(X > m + \ell \mid X > m) &= P(X> \ell) && \forall  m,\ell= 0,1,2,3,3...
\end{align}

How do I show that if X is a discrete random variable, whose values is in $\mathbb{N}$ and (1) is true, then it’s geometric distributed?

Answer (score 0):

It is known as memoryless property.
Only discrete distribution to follow this property is geometric distribution and for the continuous case it is exponential distribution.
If you want to prove this :-
$P(X\geq l+m | X\geq l) = 1- P(X\leq l+m | X\geq l). \\$
Apply bayes rule to the above expression to get the result